# How to create a bootable USB for Debian on Mac with Apple Silicon?

Tags: usb, macos, bootable

I thoroughly went through the official and up-to-date articles from Debian. I will list some resources below:

- https://lists.debian.org/debian-cd/2023/12/threads.html
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/CreateUSBMedia
- https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/amd64/ch04s03.en.html#usb-copy-isohybrid

The `ISO` image file that I downloaded: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-12.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso

I have followed many articles. I have succeeded using `diskutil` and  `dd` as described in this [article](https://blog.pcrisk.com/mac/12640-how-to-write-an-iso-file-to-an-usb-drive-on-mac).

Following this article led to a successful [output](https://postimg.cc/G9q49LqY):

From the looks of it, the USB should be working now. However, I have plugged it into the laptop on which I want to boot Debian —  have chosen the USB stick as the first disk to boot from — tried booting it as a temporary disk…

In the latter case, it just returned to the UEFI screen without doing anything. I have read on Debian's page that some old laptops may have a “broken UEFI” which could prevent it from working. However, this is not a probable answer at this point.

Some additional info about Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad T430, has Windows 10 already installed.

I am riding on the assumption that, I can uninstall the Windows OS after booting Debian when creating a partition. I have used this [article](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/boot-your-windows-10-pc-usb-flash-drive/#ftoc-heading-3) for info about booting from USB.

My question is similar to the post: [How to make a bootable Debian USB on a Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293969/how-to-make-bootable-debian-usb-on-mac). However, the solutions provided there did not work, and the latest answers are about 6 years old.

Edit: In my case, the issue was that the GPT partition table was not selected. When you receive a warning that your disk could not be read by the computer and must be ejected, don't worry. Try booting the USB anyway, and it should work. (This may be the case for you because Mac cannot read exFAT). **Flashing with Balena Etcher worked for me.**

Comment: I have used p7zip in Ubuntu to just extract an ISO to a FAT32 formatted flash drive with boot,esp flags. Not sure what extraction tool you have? Use gpt partitioning on flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Etcher from Balena: https://etcher.balena.io/

It works on macOS(Intel & Apple Silicon), Linux and Windows.  I downloaded the ISO and was able to successfully write it to a USB-C drive on my M1-based MacBook Pro using this software package.